# my bootstrap based mobile site looks zoom out

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed wallpaper download & meme generation site named: `dekhbehen.com`. The problem is that when the site is viewed through smartphone, it appears to be zoom out. I am providing the url:-
`dekhbehen.com/Wallpaper/Valentine-Day/index.html`
Just because of this, I developed homepage of my mobile site using `jQuery` mobile & desktop site using `Bootstrap`.

Comment: Just configurate <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: If you see the page source you will come to know that I have already applied meta viewport but still i am getting the same problem

Answer (score 6):

A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like `width=600` or to the special value device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)

The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, and `user-scalable` properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I am already aware about meta viewport as you can see even in the page source. Have you visited the site through your mobile

Comment: Just saved my life with this. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you @BlakeConnally

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that it doesn't work.
Try to use next:

```
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: extend-to-zoom;
}

@-ms-viewport{
    width: extend-to-zoom;
    zoom: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Where should i apply it. I dont about the above code.

Comment: add it in your style CSS